# Flask SQAlchemy + SQLite NOT NULL failure

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a simple registration form and it will insert into my SQLite DB. But it fails, by showing that the `email` column contradicting with the `NOT NULL` constraint. Even though the input from `email` is being submitted and recognized.

**The DB model (Flask SQLAlchemy):**

```
class Registration(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50))
    username = db.Column(db.String(20))
    password = db.Column(db.String(350))
```

**Registration code:**

```
form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data
        email = form.email.data
        password = bcrypt.hashpw(form.password.data.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt(14))

        # Query DB for existing username
        user = Registration.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        # Query DB for existing email
        email = Registration.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        # If username exits
        if user:
            flash("Sorry that username is already taken, please choose another!")
            return render_template('register.html', form=form)

        # If email exists
        elif email:
            flash('That email is already associated with another account, please use another!')
            return render_template('register.html', form=form)

        else:
            new_user = Registration(email=email, username=username, password=password)
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Thanks for registering, {u}!".format(u=username))

            return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

**Error:**

```
(sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: registration.email [SQL: 'INSERT INTO registration (email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (None, 'test_user', b'$2b$14$fiL14w35s.kckAY5timb9uE0d9pQ/K9RZpRuNPBlnsKl3FHaQfFoG')]
```

But it is showing that the email address is found:

```
2017-03-20 13:35:19,082 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('insert@gmail.com', 1, 0)
```

But then the 2 lines after show:

```
2017-03-20 13:35:19,084 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO registration (email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
2017-03-20 13:35:19,084 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (None, 'test_user', b'$2b$14$fiL14w35s.kckAY5timb9uE0d9pQ/K9RZpRuNPBlnsKl3FHaQfFoG')
```

Why would it try to insert `None` for `email` even though it shows the actual email inputted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you run this query:

`email = Registration.query.filter_by(email=email).first()`

You are overwriting your `email` variable with the results of that query. If no matching entry is found, you're replacing `email` with `None`, which then leads to your problem.

Also interestingly, I can't actually see why your `email` column has a `NOT NULL` constraint - your definition of that column is:

`email = db.Column(db.String(50))`

which doesn't specify any constraints for the column. If you want to ensure this column is never NULL, you should change this to:

`email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)`